# Removing methods when extending from an abstract class?

Tags: php, oop

I'm reading through a blog post on the factory method in php, https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/the-factory-design-pattern-explained-by-example/142 . Based on this I have:

```
abstract class Toy {
   public $name  = '';
   public $price  = 0;

   public function prepare() {
       echo $this->name. ' is prepared';
   }

   public function package() {
       echo $this->name. ' is packaged';
   }

   public function label(){
       echo $this->name . ' is priced at '.$this->price;
   }
}


class NY_Car extends Toy {
    public $name  = 'Car';
    public $price = 20;
```

In the article we have:

> It turns out that the NyToysFactory class has been modified by developers at the remote branch because the staff doesn't want to do packaging and labeling work. They've modified produceToy() by removing its label() and package() functions.

This leaves me with the question: if you were to build a class  NY_Car extending Toy how could you remove the methods prepare() and package() ?

Comment: you don't remove methods, you can override them and throw exception at best. I'm not sure that "how remove methods from extended class" is your real question

Comment: I may be phrasing it wrong, but I'm trying to understand how to write the code discussed in the blockquote above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blockquote states that developers modified the remote branch... Or in other words, they manaully removed those methods. Afaik, there is no way in any language to remove methods by extending a class. However, you can make methods in your parent class inaccessible to the children (the classes that extend your parent class) by declaring those methods 'private'. For example:

```
private function package() {
    echo $this->name. ' is packaged';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it some cases you may want to make them available to the children, how could you accommodate that?

Comment: If you want a parent class with methods that are only available to that class and its children you would use protected methods: `protected function package(){...` here's a link with more details on the matter: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php